# How can I specify an alias in ERIC python IDE

Tags: 14.04, python

I have a code in python which sets an environment variable and an alias to another code.

eg - when i run 'install.py' I get the environment variable and alias to a code named pyfem.py.

I can use these and run command

'pyfem (filename).pro'

perfectly through the terminal to execute the program.

But when I use Eric, I am unable to run the program even after setting the environment variable in the run script dialog box.

I have not found a way to set the alias to pyfem.So I feel that might be the problem.

Can someone please let me know how to set an alias through Eric. I have ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks

Comment: Did you print out the value you get from the ENV variable when running in Eric?

Answer (score 0):

This is Python 2.7 code and both python programs in the same directory.

**call_script.py**

```
import os
from subprocess import call

if  "OTHER_PROGRAM" in os.environ.keys():
    program_name =  os.environ["OTHER_PROGRAM"]
    print "will execute",   program_name
    call([program_name ,"some_file.pro"])
else:
    print "OTHER_PROGRAM env variable not defined"
```

**other.py** (must be marked executable  - i.e.: chmod +x other.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

print "executing in other.py"

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print "was passed value of ", sys.argv[1]
else:
    print "no arguments were passed"
```

[image]

outputs:

```
executing in other.py
was passed value of  some_file.pro
```